# Extract a string enclosed between a pattern and a delimiter in Unix

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, sed

I am trying to parse SQL source or Shell scripts trying to extract object names from it using `bash/awk/sed/perl`.

Sample Text - Lets say a text file contains commands like below :

```
CALL DBUSER.Compiled_Object_Name('....parameters...');
```

My intention is to parse the text file to fetch one line at a time. I am using a Do While in bash to achieve this.

Next step is to parse such a line to extract the below string which is the Object name.

```
DBUSER.Compiled_Object_Name
```

Here, `DBUSER` is a repeating pattern, and always delimited by `(`

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat test.sql 
CALL DBUSER.Compiled_Object_Name('....parameters...');
CALL DBUSER.Object_Name_1('....parameters...');
# WHATEVER
CALL DBUSER.Compiled_Object_Name('....parameters...');
```

Grep/Egrep:

```
grep -o 'DBUSER\.[^\(]\{1,\}' test.sql
egrep -o 'DBUSER\.[^\(]+' test.sql
```

Perl:

```
perl -ne 'next unless /DBUSER/; ($m) = $_ =~ /(DBUSER\.[^\(]+)/; print "$m\n";' test.sql
```

Result from both:

```
DBUSER.Compiled_Object_Name
DBUSER.Object_Name_1
DBUSER.Compiled_Object_Name
```